# Why passing multiple integer value parameter in SSRS throws a conversion error?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, int

My procedure is something like that, very simple.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
    @NoteStoreType INT 
AS 
    SELECT 
        Column1, Column2, Column3  
    FROM  
        tblNoteStore
    WHERE 
        tblNoteStore.Type IN (COALESCE(@NoteStoreType, tblNoteStore.Type))
```

My dataset to populate available parameter values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tblNoteStore.Type, 
    lstNoteTypes.Description
FROM
    tblNoteStore 
INNER JOIN
    lstNoteTypes ON tblNoteStore.Type = lstNoteTypes.NoteTypeID
ORDER BY    
    lstNoteTypes.Description
```

Returns this result:

[image]

Then I go to Report Parameter Properties to Allow Multiple values:

[image]

Now setting available values:

[image]

Then if I run the report with more than one value, it gives me an error:

[image]

I know that it happens because SSRS treats multiple values as string, passing them by comma.

But what would be the work around in this situation?

Comment: Please show the main report dataset query.  You say this works ok with one value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to avoid dynamic SQL as it's harder to maintain. You can apply this parameter as a filter in the SQL or you can apply it at the dataset level after the query runs.

Adding a dataset filter is pretty straightforward. The only draw back is that it is less efficient. If the speed difference is insignificant, it's a good option.
[image]

In some versions of SSRS you can use a regular `IN` statement in the SQL:

```
WHERE tblNoteStore.Type IN (@NoteStoreType)
```

If that doesn't work with your version, you can also use a custom Split function in your SQL to break the comma separated string into individual values. There are many answers devoted to that specific topic already.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `@NoteStoreType INT` in your stored procedure is a single INTEGER, not a list of integer values. You should try with a dynamic query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
@NoteStoreType NVARCHAR(2048) 
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @cmd = 'SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 
              FROM  tblNoteStore
              WHERE tblNoteStore.Type IN (' + @NoteStoreType + ')';

  EXEC (@cmd);

END
GO
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/NWLLU92997

Comment: Thanks. Great idea, but my procedure much bigger than the one I post it. It also has 6 different parameters.

Comment: Simply single quote it, and take care of your parameters.